# Constraining equation that includes multiple variables at a boundary using GEKKO

Tags: python, gekko

I have a system of differential equations that I'm trying to perform some optimal control on, using Gekko. In particular, I have a point-mass orbiting a planet and would simply like to raise its orbit using modelled thrusters as control inputs. In order to set the final radial position and velocity at the new raised orbit, I need to set the following boundary conditions:

```
sqrt(x[-1]**2 + y[-1]**2) = r_final
sqrt(vx[-1]**2 + vy[-1]**2) = v_final
```

Where `(x,y)` is the Cartesian position of the point-mass, and `(vx,vy)` is its velocity components, and the `[-1]` notation implies the last element in the trajectory. Furthermore, `r_final` is the desired altitude of the new orbit, and `v_final` is the desired speed of the new orbit.

So far I have only been able to find functions in Gekko that constrain a *single* variable (e.g. `fix()`, `fix_final()` and `fix_initial()`), however I couldn't find any functions or examples that had more complex boundary conditions that included multiple variables.

Looking at the above-mentioned example, I'm hoping to use Gekko to constrain the final radial position and speed at the new orbit similar to the following piece of code:

```
m.fix(m.sqrt(x**2 + y**2), pos=len(m.time)-1,val=r_final)
m.fix(m.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2), pos=len(m.time)-1,val=v_final)
```

Is something like this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only variables can be directly fixed in `gekko`. Below are three options. I recommend trying Option 2 first and then use Option 3 if the solver can't find a solution.

**Option 1: Define Equations**

With terminal complex expressions, use a `final` parameter that is non-zero only at the final time point with an equation definition.

```py
z = np.linspace(0,tf,n); z[-1]=1
final = m.Param(z)
m.Equation(final*(x**2 + y**2 - r_final**2)==0)
m.Equation(final*(m.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2) - v_final)==0)
```

Don't use `m.Equation(final*(x**2 + y**2)==r_final**2)` or it will be infeasible with `0==r_final**2` before the final point. These equations create many `0==0` equations and can cause a problem for the gradient-based solvers thinking there are too few degrees of freedom.

**Option 2: Define Variables and `fix_final()`**

Another way to do this is to define two new variables and fix those at the final time point with `fix_final()`.

```py
r,v = m.Array(m.Var,2)
m.Equations([r**2==x**2 + y**2,
             v**2==vx**2 + vy**2])
m.fix_final(r,r_final)
m.fix_final(v,v_final)
```

**Option 3: Minimize Soft Constraints**

If the solver isn't able to find a feasible solution, try setting a soft constraint instead of `fix()` or `fix_final()`.

```py
m.Minimize(final*100*(r-r_final)**2)
m.Minimize(final*200*(v-v_final)**2)
```

**Additional Info**

It is also possible to [minimize final time](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MinimizeFinalTime) for the maneuver by making `tf` a variable with `m.Minimize(tf)`. The [Bryson Benchmark problem](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MidtermExam2016) (see Problem 2) has four examples of specifying terminal constraints.

[image: Bryson Benchmark]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Build Model ############################
m = GEKKO()

#define time space
nt = 101
m.time = np.linspace(0,1.5,nt)

#Parameters
u = m.MV(value =0, lb = -1, ub = 1) 
u.STATUS = 1
u.DCOST = 0.0001  # slight penalty to discourage MV movement

#Variables
x1 = m.Var(value=0.5)
x2 = m.Var(value =  0)
myObj = m.Var()

#Equations
m.Equation(myObj.dt() == 0.5*x1**2)
m.Equation(x1.dt() == u + x2)
m.Equation(x2.dt() == -u)

f = np.zeros(nt)
f[-1] = 1
final = m.Param(value=f)

# Four options for final constraints x1(tf)=0 and x2(tf)=0
option = 2 # best option = 3 (fix endpoints directly)
if option == 1:
    # most likely to cause DOF issues because of many 0==0 equations
    m.Equation(final*x1 == 0)
    m.Equation(final*x2 == 0) 
elif option == 2:
    # inequality constraint approach is better but there are still
    #   many inactive equations not at the endpoint
    m.Equation((final*x1)**2 <= 0)
    m.Equation((final*x2)**2 <= 0)
elif option == 3: #requires GEKKO version >= 0.0.3a2
    # fix the value just at the endpoint (best option)
    m.fix(x1,pos=nt-1,val=0)
    m.fix(x2,pos=nt-1,val=0)
else:
    #penalty method ("soft constraint") that may influence the
    # optimal solution because there is just one combined objective
    # and it may interfere with minimizing myObj
    m.Obj(1000*(final*x1)**2)
    m.Obj(1000*(final*x2)**2)

m.Obj(myObj*final)

########################################
#Set Global Options and Solve
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.NODES = 3
m.options.MV_TYPE = 1
m.options.SOLVER = 1  # APOPT solver

#Solve
m.solve() # (remote=False) for local solution

# Print objective value
print('Objective (myObj): ' + str(myObj[-1]))

########################################
#Plot Results
plt.figure()
plt.plot(m.time, x1.value, 'y:', label = '$x_1$')
plt.plot(m.time, x2.value, 'r--', label = '$x_2$')
plt.plot(m.time, u.value, 'b-', label = 'u')
plt.plot(m.time, myObj.value,'k-',label='Objective')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```